# V'ahavta l're'eicha kamocha -- re'eicha velo akum?

Tags: gentiles, parashas-kedoshim, ahavat-yisrael, love-thy-neighbor

Do any rabbinical sources hold that the commandment in Leviticus [19:18](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9920/jewish/Chapter-19.htm#v=18) to love one's neighbour as oneself (ואהבת לרעך כמוך) applies to non-Jews as well as Jews?

Comment: Why do you think there are such authorities?

Comment: There are authorities who view the prohibition of homosexuality as relating to hermaphrodites, why wouldn't there be an opinion who says that says that v'ahavta l're'eicha kamocha is applicable to goyim? It certainly makes more sense than completely editorialising an issur.

Comment: There might be authorities who think Matza has to be purple, but until you indicate why you think they might exist, asking about them is a poor question. (Incidentally I don't know of any authorities who limit the prohibition on homosexuality to hermaphrodites.)

Comment: @DoubleAA, I suspect that sources exist, however having never done research in the question (my rabbinic Hebrew is also nonexistent) I don't have the information.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Your question might better be phrased "does anyone hold" rather than "who holds" as the latter implies you are aware that someone does and just don't know who.

Comment: I know that there are such sources, but I don't remember what they were. In high school some students gave a non-Jewish teacher a really horrible time, so one of my friends took a public speaking project in English as an opportunity to give a rundown of said sources.

Comment: I'm going with the notion that no such opinion exists among any authority who holds the talmud binding. Simply because when Hillel summarized the 'whole' Torah to the prospective convert, he said what you hate do not do to others, in other words viahavta lireiacha kamocha, which only takes effect for jews. Of vourse that was the opposite of your case but we see that there is no 'reacha' between jews and nonjews.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14324/5323

Comment: Related: [Does ‘Love Your Neighbor As Yourself’ apply only to Jews?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95265/17604), [May one love a non-Jew?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14324/17604)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the term רעך (your fellow/neighbor, friend) is generally understood as applying strictly to one's fellow Jew, R' David Sears brings a number of sources related to [loving every one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14327/899), including one which see a broader application of this verse in his book **Compassion for Humanity in the Jewish Tradition**:

> Love for one's neighbor means that we should love all people no matter
>   to which nation they belong or what language they speak. For all men
>   are created in the Divine image and all engage in improving
>   civilization...Our love of humanity should take no exception to any
>   nation or individual....Therefore, not only does [love of one's
>   fellow] apply to the Jewish people but to all mankind. We should love
>   all nations and include all peoples in this universal principle, "the
>   stranger and the native son" alike, all who inhabit the earth. Let
>   every man strive for the benefit of his fellow, in a spirit of
>   mutuality, whether in physical concerns or in financial matters, for
>   the collective good and for the improvement of society. Loving one's
>   neighbor means that we should befriend all human beings. (Rabbi
>   Pinchas Eliyahu of Vilna, *Sefer HaBris*, sect. II, discourse
>   13)."(page 6 and 7)

He subsequently relates a story about [Rabbi Pinchas of Koretz](http://asimplejew.blogspot.com/2005/09/rebbe-pinchas-of-koretz.html) who was very pleased when presented with a *sefer* teaching this idea, presumably the aforementioned *Sefer HaBris*.