# Ahavat haGer – Geirei Tzedek or Toshvim?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, mitzvah, love

I've heard at various times that the Mitzvah of Ahavat haGer (loving the stranger, cf. [Devarim 10:19](http://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.10.19)) refers to either (non-Jewish) resident aliens or converts. Is there any discussion about which of these (if not both) the mitzvah actually refers to?

Related: [What happened to the mitzvah to love the stranger?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60788/what-happened-to-the-mitzvah-to-love-the-stranger)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Rambam is explicit that the mitzvah of Loving the Ger applies to a convert who has "entered under the wings of the Divine presence" ie. A Ger Tzedek who has converted to Judaism, and is considered a full fledged Jew.

- See the Rambam (**דעות ו-ד**) :

> **אַהֲבַת הַגֵּר שֶׁבָּא וְנִכְנָס תַּחַת כַּנְפֵי הַשְּׁכִינָה שְׁתֵּי מִצְוֹת עֲשֵׂה**. אַחַת מִפְּנֵי שֶׁהוּא בִּכְלַל רֵעִים
> וְאַחַת מִפְּנֵי שֶׁהוּא גֵּר וְהַתּוֹרָה אָמְרָה (דברים י-יט)
> {וַאֲהַבְתֶּם אֶת הַגֵּר}. צִוָּה עַל אַהֲבַת הַגֵּר כְּמוֹ שֶׁצִּוָּה
> עַל אַהֲבַת עַצְמוֹ שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (דברים ו-ה) {וְאָהַבְתָּ אֵת ה'
> אֱלֹהֶיךָ}. הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא עַצְמוֹ אוֹהֵב גֵּרִים
> שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (דברים י-יח) {וְאֹהֵב גֵּר}:

- The Rambam in [Sefer Hamitzvos](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1155111/sc/fb_share/jewish/-.htm) is also explicit that this mitzvah refers specifically to a Convert:

> ואף על פי שהוא נכלל בעניין זה במה שכולל כל ישראל באומרו "ואהבת לרעך
> כמוך", **לפי שהגר הזה הוא גר צדק**
>
> Although he [this convert] is included in the Mitzvah of 'Love Thy
> Neighbor like Yourself' **for he is a righteous convert**.

- See the Sefer Hachinuch in Parshat Eikev, who writes as well that this mitzvah is explicitly referring to a convert to Judaism and not a Ger Toshav:

> **תלא**. מצות אהבת הגרים. [[שנצטוינו]] לאהב הגרים, כלומר, שנזהר שלא לצער
> אותם, בשום דבר, אבל נעשה להם טובה ונגמל אותם חסד כפי הראוי והיכלת,
> **והגרים הם, כל מי שנתחבר אלינו משאר האמות שהניח דתו ונכנס בדתנו, ועליהם נאמר (דברים י יט) ואהבתם את הגר וגו'**. ואף על פי שיכללהו כמו
> כן הצווי בישראל, שנאמר עליו ואהבת לרעך כמוך (מצוה רמג), **שהרי גר צדק
> בגלל רעך הוא**, הוסיף לנו השם בו מצוה מיחדת לו באהבתו
>
> These Geirim are anyone from among the Nations who has connected to
> us (The Jewish People) and left their Religion and has joined ours, on
> them it scripture says "You Shall Love the Convert"

- However, the Chofetz Chaim in his compilation of the 613 Mitzvos ([ספר המצוות הקצר מצוות עשה סא׳](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/mitzvot-katzar/mitzvot-katzar01.pdf)) writes that the Mitzvah to love the stranger applies to a Ger Toshav as well:

> **סא**. מצות עשה לאהוב את הגר. שנאמר: "ואהבתם את הגר" (דברים י, יט). וזוהי
> מצוה נוספת על ואהבת לרעך כמוך (שהרי הגר הוא גם כן בכלל ישראל). והקב"ה
> אוהב את הגר דכתיב "ואוהב גר לתת לו לחם ושמלה" (דברים י, יח), ונאמר
> "ואתם ידעתם את נפש הגר" (שמות כג, ט), **ופירוש גר כאן, הוא שבא מארץ
> אחרת ומעיר אחרת לגור אתנו, ומכל שכן גר שנתגייר.** ונוהג בכל מקום ובכל
> זמן בזכרים ונקבות.

Comment: Both of these sources leave something to be desired, add it could be argued that a ger toshav has also joined our dat and come under the wings if the shekhina.

Comment: @mevaqesh how do you translate correctly the chinuch saying "ונכנס בדתנו״? A Ger Toshav may have left idolatry. But he for sure does not enter into ours.

Comment: That depends, of course on how broad the term dat is and how much one looks at the ger Toshiba as being a partial convert requiring a court to approve.

Comment: @mevaqesh דת means religion. Perhaps you have sources of reasons to doubt that translation?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44443/discussion-on-answer-by-mefaresh-ahavat-hager--geirei-tzedek-or-toshvim).

Comment: Much improved IMHO.

Comment: Mefaresh, I feel that your answer would work somewhat better if it also brought sources which disagreed with the Rambam's assessment.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I did the Chofetz Chaim

Comment: But the Chofetz Chaim also agrees with the Rambam's interpretation. A fuller answer would also bring sources who hold that ahavas hager refers only to gerim toshvim IMO

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt the Chofetz Chaim disagrees with the Rambam. The says it's referring only to a ger Tzedek. While the CC writes it applies to a ger toshav as well. Point being there is no one who holds that It only refers to ger toshav. The only disagreement is whether it *also* applies to a Toshav.

Comment: Mefaresh, what I mean is that someone who holds that only a toshav is covered by the halacha would be what I'd need to accept this answer.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt that opinion doesn't exist based off every I have seen imo

Comment: I'm surprised. Usually, there's at least one da'at yachid who holds against every other makor

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt generally. But not always